# How to create google cloud instance in available zone?

Tags: google-api, cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, continuous-deployment

I have a scheduled builds and deployment of a project on UAT environment using Bamboo. Bamboo executes script to create google cloud instance and run the project inside created instance.

The problem is when I create instance using 

`gcloud compute instances create myproject --image cos-stable-61-9765-79-0 --image-project cos-cloud --zone us-central1-b`

I get the following error sometimes:

`The zone 'projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later.`

[I know resource availability in regions/zones are not publicly available](https://serverfault.com/questions/845075/how-do-i-avoid-an-overbooked-gce-zone).

My question is How can I create compute engine instances in resource available region/zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with many API issues, the answer is "retry". First, retry the request in the same zone as the issue might have only lasted a brief time as hinted at in the answer you linked.  If a zone remains unavailable, retry with a different zone. There is almost always at least one zone in each region with enough capacity.